# CSS flex: prevent overflow of grandchild (i.e., force scroll)

Tags: css, flexbox

Given the following:

```html
<main>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <nav><button>Home</button> - <button>Contact</button> - <button>About</button></nav>
  <br>
  <div class=wrapper>
    <b>List header</b>
    <ul></ul>
  </div>
</main>
```

How to force `ul` to scroll, and *not* overflow `main` nor `.wrapper`? I.e., the scrollbar should appear for `ul`, not `main`, nor `.wrapper`. Without hardcoding values.

I tried the following CSS but it fails. It would work if I was trying to scroll `.wrapper`, but I'm trying to scroll its child.

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
.wrapper {
  flex: 1;
}
ul {
  overflow: auto; /* How to force this to scroll? */
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/mustafa0x/pen/oNLXyxm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`block` elements, by default, grow as much as they are allowed to. This is why your `ul` element doesn't display any bars.

Try setting a height, like `height: 150px` and you will see some scrollbars.

```js
// Lorem ipsum
const $ = q => document.querySelector(q);
const url = 'https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&sentences=100';
fetch(url).then(r => r.json()).then(data => {
   $('ul').innerHTML = data[0].split('. ').map(l => '<li>' + l).join('\n');
});
```

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 100vh;
  
  /* Styling */
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.wrapper {
  flex: 1;
}
ul {
  overflow: auto; /* How to force this to scroll? */
  height: 150px;
  /* Styling */
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <nav><button>Home</button> - <button>Contact</button> - <button>About</button></nav>
  <br>
  <div class=wrapper>
    <b>List header</b>
    <ul></ul>
  </div>
</main>
```

Since you are not allowed to use fixed values, and also not allowed to modify the HTML, what you can do is to introduce another flex.

flex items, by default, have `min-height: auto`. Which means a flex item cannot be smaller than the size of its content.

To override that, you need to set `min-height: 0` on your flex item, in this case `.wrapper`. That will cause the `.wrapper` to reach until the end of the screen.

But still, the `ul` element will keep increasing. To prevent that, without using fixed units, you need to convert the `.wrapper` into a column-directed flexbox as well.

```js
// Lorem ipsum
const $ = q => document.querySelector(q);
const url = 'https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&sentences=100';
fetch(url).then(r => r.json()).then(data => {
   $('ul').innerHTML = data[0].split('. ').map(l => '<li>' + l).join('\n');
});
```

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 0;
}
ul {
  overflow: auto; /* How to force this to scroll? */
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <nav><button>Home</button> - <button>Contact</button> - <button>About</button></nav>
  <br>
  <div class=wrapper>
    <b>List header</b>
    <ul></ul>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks. As mentioned, hardcoding values isn't an option for my use case.

Comment: Is it possible to rearrange your elements then?

Comment: If possible, just move the `<b>` one level up, before the wrapper, and add move the `overflow: auto` from the `ul` to the wrapper.

Comment: Not in the actual web app unfortunately.

Comment: @mustafa.0x I have updated my answer with a solution following those contraints.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this approach in testing but mistakenly applied min-height to the child. Appreciated.